# how to accept 2 extention for a file in python?

Tags: python

I'm discovering files from my template directory one of them should be `copier.yaml`, to do so I'm using the following:

```py
copier_yaml = template_dir / "copier.yaml"  # a pathlib.Path 
params = yaml.safe_load(copier_yaml.read_text())
```

Now I realize to be fully compatible with `copier` I should be accepting both `.yaml` and `.yml` extentions, is there a pythonic way to do so ?

Comment: Try with this one, and if it fails, use the other one? Or check before if any of them exists?

Comment: So there is no way to deal with alternate extensions ? like jpeg, jpg, JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution for a specific set:

- you are looking for a single file with a specific name
- the file can have any of the alternate extension of the file type (e.g. "yaml", "yml")

```py
from pathlib import Path 

dir = Path("<dir_path>")
file = next(f for f in dir.glob("<filename>.*") if f.suffix in [".yml", ".yaml"])
```

By using this solution you will get 1 single file or raise an error if the file does not exist.